# How to pass arguments from one function to another function in bash scripting?

Tags: bash, functions

I can do this in Python:

```py
def one(arg1):
    return arg1

def two(a,b):
    result=a+b
    return one(result)

two(1,3)
```

And it will work. But how do I do the same in a bash script?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try that argument passing this way:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

function one(){
    # Print the result to stdout
    echo "$1"
}

function two() {
    local one=$1
    local two=$2
    # Do arithmetic and assign the result to
    # a variable named result
    result=$((one + two))
    # Pass the result of the arithmetic to
    # the function "one" above and catch it
    # in the variable $1
    one "$result"
}
# Call the function "two"
two 1 3
```

Comment: One thing that I've noticed when passing variables in functions across machines (like ssh) is the tendency for special characters  like my_pwd='!Abc123' to get interpreted.  A way to fix that is to declare it like so  in the EOT setup --> my_pwd=\\$my_pwd